# Why is there such a result?

Tags: go

I wrote a golang script to scan for open ports and use sync.WaitGourp to control the number of goroutines.

When the goroutine is too large, such as 2000, the result is different from 1000.

Similar to exiting early. code show as below

```golang
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for job := range jobs {
        _, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", job.host, job.port), time.Millisecond*1500)
        if err != nil {
            results <- Result{job, false}
        } else {
            results <- Result{job, true}
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i < 65535; i++ {
            jobs <- Job{host, i}
        }
        close(jobs)
    }()

    go func() {
        for result := range results {
            if result.status {
                fmt.Println(result.job, "open")
            }
        }
    }()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

when 1000

> {127.0.0.1 80} open
> {127.0.0.1 631} open
> {127.0.0.1 3306} open
> {127.0.0.1 6379} open
> {127.0.0.1 33060} open

when 2000

> {127.0.0.1 80} open
> {127.0.0.1 631} open

I want 2000 to output all ports like 1000

Comment: "When the goroutine is too large, such as 2000, the result is different from 1000." Different how? What is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: I would guess that the issue is that some of your net.DialTimeouts are failing because you're trying to open too many ports rather than there being no listener. This should be an OS limitation. Can you find the exact value (between 1000 and 2000) where the results start changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the results channel when workers are done.  Process the results in the main goroutine.

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(&wg)
}

go func() {
    for i := 1; i < 65535; i++ {
        jobs <- Job{host, i}
    }

    // No more jobs, exit from worker loops.
    close(jobs)

    // Wait for workers to write all results and exit.
    wg.Wait()

    // No more results, exit from main loop.
    close(results)

}()

for result := range results {
    if result.status {
        fmt.Println(result.job, "open")
    }
}
```

[View the complete program on the GoLang PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/_ZDo2Y_PABr).

Comment: Thanks, but when I run your code in Linux, the problem still arises.

Comment: @ze7o, then ask a new question with precise problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

You do not wait for the two "non-worker" goroutines in `main`, so as soon as `wg.Wait()` there returns, the process shuts down, tearing down any outstanding goroutines.

Since one of them is processing the results, this appears to you as if not all the tasks were processed (and this is true).

Comment: Thank you, but I have encountered a new problem, which is normal under Windows, but not Linux.